# Solution of the congruence $X^5 \equiv 1 \pmod {25}$ with lift

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

Can someone explain me the right steps for the solution of this congruence using the method of the lift?

> $X^5 \equiv  1 \pmod {25}$

I know that I can write this as $f(x) = X^5-1 \equiv  0 \pmod {25}$.

Obviously $25=5^2$

Then I start solving $X^5-1 \equiv  0 \pmod {5}$.

Here I find that the only solution for this is $X_0\equiv  1 \pmod {5}$.

So I proceed with the lift $x \rightarrow x^2 $ finding $M=0$ and $f'(X_0)=5\equiv 0 \pmod {5}$. In this case there are $5$ solutions writable as $x=1+5t$ and those are the set $S=[ 1,6,11,16,21]$.

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: In case others are confused: it seems that the asker is referring to [Hensel lifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Hensel_lifting).

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Right now, it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: Added more context and a sketch of solution

Comment: You are correct

Comment: It helps to have a good understanding of the group $(\Bbb Z/25\Bbb Z)^times$ . With that, I think you’ll see that your guess is on the mark. But personally, I don’t see this as a lifting question…

Comment: Ok so this is not the lifting? Sorry I'm so confuse about the terminology

Comment: I would have called it a lifting question.  You're exactly applying the usual method from Hensel's Theorem.